# recursion in return dictionary get method

Tags: python, recursion, return, return-value

Using a MWE. The function `foo` works alright, `bar` does not and raises a *"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"* exception. Any hints?

```
def foo(i1, i2):
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    if i1[1] < i2[0]: return "<"
    return inverse_map[foo(i2, i1)]

def bar(i1, i2):
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    return {
        i1[1] < i2[0]: "<"
    }.get(True, inverse_map[bar(i2, i1)])

i1, i2 = (0, 2), (4, 6)
print foo(i2, i1), ">"
print bar(i2, i1), ">"
```

Comment: Google for "recursion base condition"

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that the base condition would have been the entry `i1[1] < i2[0]: "<"` in the dictionary, which would exit the recursion. Am I missing something? Hmm, probably need to have a look on the `get` method in more detail as I might be missing something.

Comment: Yes had further look in the `get` method and not any clearer what's wrong here. Still confused as I thought the base condition here is `i1[1] < i2[0]: "<"`.

Answer (score 2):

The python dictionary `get` method checks the default value first, thus, in the `bar` function, it will recursively call `bar` before `return` value. Your code can be converted to the following format, which cause dead recursive:

```
def foo(i1, i2):
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    if i1[1] < i2[0]: return "<"
    return inverse_map[foo(i2, i1)]

def bar(i1, i2):
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    d = {i1[1] < i2[0] : "<"}
    inverse = inverse_map[bar(i2,i1)]
    return d.get(True,inverse)

i1, i2 = (0, 2), (4, 6)
print foo(i1, i2), ">"
print bar(i2, i1), ">"
```

A snapshot of dictionary `get` implementation is shown below:

```
static PyObject *
dict_get(register PyDictObject *mp, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *key;
    PyObject *failobj = Py_None;
    PyObject *val = NULL;
    long hash;
    PyDictEntry *ep;
    #commented by myself, get function first check default value
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "get", 1, 2, &key, &failobj))
        return NULL;

    if (!PyString_CheckExact(key) ||
        (hash = ((PyStringObject *) key)->ob_shash) == -1) {
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
        if (hash == -1)
            return NULL;
    }
    ep = (mp->ma_lookup)(mp, key, hash);
    if (ep == NULL)
        return NULL;
    val = ep->me_value;
    if (val == NULL)
        val = failobj;
    Py_INCREF(val);
    return val;
}
```

[python dictionary implementation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c)

Comment: Thanks didn't know that about `get`. Did something similar by having a lambda relation in it, but I like yours more since it does it in one. On a sidenote timing the `foo` and the `bar` methods I didn't see any significant difference, in fact `foo` with the if statements seemed more stable in timings while `bar` with the dictionary had some spikes. That is with about a dozen of conditions in both. Strange. Need to time yours above.

Comment: Following earlier comment. Unfortunately, I tested your script and it still gives infinite recursion, both in forward as well as in inverse.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've coded this, you have no exit condition from bar.  i1[1] < i2[0] is an expression for a dictionary key, so you recur every time.  Look up the Python ternary operator; I think that's what you're trying to use.  Something like

```
return "<" if i1[1] < i2[0] else inverse_map[bar(i2, i1)]
```

... which works.

In the future, add some tracing print statements, like so:

```
def foo(i1, i2):
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    print "ENTER foo", i1, i2
    if i1[1] < i2[0]:
        return "<"
    return inverse_map[foo(i2, i1)]


def bar(i1, i2):
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    print "ENTER bar", i1, i2
    return {
        i1[1] < i2[0]: "<"
    }.get(True, inverse_map[bar(i2, i1)])

i1, i2 = (0, 2), (4, 6)
print foo(i2, i1), ">"
print bar(i2, i1), ">"
```

Comment: The key will be `True` or `False`, depends on the value `i1[1] < i2[0]`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, ternary operator is not an option as there multiple cases.

Comment: You can nest ternary operators, just like if statements.  However, they do get hard to read rather soon.

Answer (score 0):

To my question above, this is the only way I found to do the recursion.

```
def bar(i1, i2):
    d = lambda i1, i2: {i1[1] < i2[0]: "<"}.get(True)
    inverse_map = {"<": ">"}
    a = d(i1, i2)
    return a if a else inverse_map[d(i2, i1)]
```